# I want to set datatable column datatype as date time with specific format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I want to set the datetime  datatype to a column with specific format MM/DD/YYYY. Am using the below code but its changing in different system.. like this one system having '5-01-2012' and another having '01-05-2012'. how can i manage this changing please help me ...

```
  dt.Columns[0].ColumnName = "S.No"; dt.Columns[1].ColumnName = "Emp_No";
                dt.Columns[2].ColumnName = "PF A/c Number"; dt.Columns[3].ColumnName = "Employee_Name";
                dt.Columns[4].ColumnName = "Father's Name"; dt.Columns[5].ColumnName = "Month";
                dt.Columns[6].ColumnName = "Wages"; dt.Columns[7].ColumnName = "EPF";
                dt.Columns[8].ColumnName = "EPF/Diff"; dt.Columns[9].ColumnName = "EPS";
                dt.Columns[10].ColumnName = "Refund  of Advances"; dt.Columns[11].ColumnName = "Non cont. services";
                dt.Columns[12].ColumnName = "DOL"; dt.Columns[13].ColumnName = "Reason";


   dt.Columns["Month"].DataType = typeof(DateTime);
```

Comment: This thread explains it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209829/is-it-possible-to-format-a-date-column-of-a-datatable

Comment: How and what are you using to display this data, maybe you could set up a specific format on that control.

Comment: am using windows application . please explain briefly ...

Comment: My project runs correctly in my system. Suppose i ll run in another system means it returns error what i do?

Comment: @Fernando I hope you are assigning this as datasource to some control which is displaying it on the form, need details on what and how you are using the same.

Answer (score 0):

Date/Time format It is based on locale of user.