# Changing DATETIME format in datatable column without using loop in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, datatable

I have a Data Table that has a column 'subscribeDate' that has dates in MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss  format. I would like to change all the dates in this column to MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss format. Is there a way that I can do it without running a loop?

Comment: What is the datatype of the column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would hope that the values in the `DataTable` are of type `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.
Assuming that's the case, they don't *have* a format. They're just dates and times. How you convert them to a string is up to you.

If they're *not* already in an appropriate data type, you should try to change how you obtain the data to start with. Convert it from a string format to a more appropriate data type as early as you possibly can, and only convert it *back* to a string when you really need to.

You haven't explained how you're displaying the `DataTable`, but most ways that I'm aware of allow you to specify a format string - *that's* where you would specify your `MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss` format. (Note `HH` rather than `hh`, to get 24 hours.)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that, if there is not some culture restrictions in your app (I don't know how works your application) with convert method.
Somethign like this:

```
myTable.Columns["Date"].Convert(
    val => DateTime.Parse(val.ToString()).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
```

Where convert function you can find in [Is it possible to format a date column of a datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209829/is-it-possible-to-format-a-date-column-of-a-datatable)