# How to change datagridview column date format when gridview has autogeneratecolumns=true

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, date-format

I am auto generating columns in gridview depending on search parameters, few columns will be added or removed.

Please suggest me a way to set the date format to `dd-mmm-yyyy` for entire column in gridview.

For now, I'm doing it using `rowdatabound`. It checks every row, So it takes time to show the results.

This is what I do in `rowdatabound`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
        System.Data.DataRowView dtview;
        DateTime dt;
        int intCounter;
        dtview = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

        for (intCounter = 0; intCounter <= dtview.Row.ItemArray.Length - 1; intCounter++)
        {
            if (dtview.Row.ItemArray[intCounter] is System.DateTime)
            {
                dt = (DateTime)dtview.Row.ItemArray[intCounter];
                e.Row.Cells[intCounter].Text = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
            }
        }
    }
```

This checks for all records and then changes based on condition.

But I want to do it better, just by identifying the column and change the date format for complete column.

Comment: can't you do it while returning the data from DataBase itself.

Comment: No, If I do it in Database, there is one more issue, So I'm not doing that. If I do in database, I can not format the date in gridview, And then the dates wont be grouped.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer:  I haven't tried this myself, but it looks possible.

A `GridView` has a public property called `ColumnsGenerator` that has a type of `IAutoFieldGenerator`.  This is the object that determines how the columns are generated.

There's already an implementation of `IAutoFieldGenerator` out there, the default one:  `GridViewColumnsGenerator`.  This is a public, non-sealed class, and you can derive a type from it.

The method you would have to override is this one:

```
public override List<AutoGeneratedField> CreateAutoGeneratedFields(
      object dataObject, Control control);
```

Note the output, a List<T> of `AutoGeneratedField`.  `AutoGeneratedField` has a property called `DataFormatString`:

```
public override string DataFormatString { get; set; }
```

So all you'd have to do is override `CreateAutoGeneratedFields`, like this:

```
public class MyDerivedGridViewColumnsGenerator : GridViewColumnsGenerator
{
   public override List<AutoGeneratedField> CreateAutoGeneratedFields(
      object dataObject, Control control)
   {
       var list = base.CreatedAutoGeneratedFields(dataObject, control);
       foreach(var field in list)
       {
         if(field.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
             field.DataFormatString = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
       }
       return list;
   }
}
```

Now, I'm not clear on how the `ColumnsGenerator` property gets set, so you might have to do it in code.  But that should be fairly simple, since `GridViewColumnsGenerator` has a parameterless constructor:

```
 // GridView myGridView;
 myGridView.ColumnsGenerator = new MyDerivedGridViewColumnsGenerator();
```

I would set it before you bind to the `GridView`, so it's in place when it's time to create the columns.

Comment: Interesting idea! Unfortunately setting `DataFormatString` throws `NotSupportedException` and `AutoGeneratedField` is sealed.

Comment: @PiotrNawrot A beautiful theory ruined by an ugly fact ... thanks for looking into it!  If you find an elegant solution, please post it!

Comment: Probably you are messing up .NET Versions: IAutoFieldGenerator is from 3.5 while GridViewColumnsGenerator is implemented in .NET 4.5

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late.  But this worked for me.  It still uses the RowDataBound() method.  But it only runs against the first row in the data source.

```
        protected void gvGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                for (int i = 0; i < ct_columns; i++)
                {
                    DataControlFieldCell dcf = e.Row.Cells[i] as DataControlFieldCell;

                    /* default date format: hide 'time' values */
                    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0 
                        && (dcf.ContainingField.GetType().Name == "BoundField"           // defined columns
                        || dcf.ContainingField.GetType().Name == "AutoGeneratedField"))  // auto-generated columns 
                    {
                        BoundField bf = dcf.ContainingField as BoundField;

                        if (bf != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(bf.DataFormatString))
                        {
                            string col_name = bf.DataField;

                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(col_name) && drv[col_name] != null)
                            {
                                if (drv[col_name].GetType().Name == "DateTime")
                                {
                                    // set format for first row
                                    string date = drv[col_name].ToString();
                                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
                                        dcf.Text = DateTime.Parse(date).ToShortDateString();

                                    // set format for other rows
                                    bf.DataFormatString = "{0:M/dd/yyyy}";  
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are binding an DataTable to Grid then Write an extension method or link Query like

```
public static void ChangeDateFormat<T>(this DataColumn column, Func<object, T> conversion)
{
   foreach(DataRow row in column.Table.Rows)
   {
    row[column] = conversion(row[column]);
   }
}
```

And to call that Method

```
dataTable.Columns["DateColumanName"].ChangeDateFormat(
val => DateTime.Parse(val.ToString()).ToString("dd/MMM/yyyy"));
```

[Actual Source code pulled from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3209829/is-it-possible-to-format-a-date-column-of-a-datatable)

 And also note you need check the existence of column and data type and the other checks to get rid of errors.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly simple solution: rather than handle each row separately, set-up the columns *before* binding the grid.

In the following example, `view` is an object that generates a regular `DataTable` and the grid view has its `AutoGenerateColumns` property set to `false`.

Essentially, you just examine the columns' data type and when its a `DateTime`, set the format you want.

```
DataTable dt = view.GetReport();

Type dateType = typeof(DateTime);
foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
{
    BoundField f =  new BoundField();
    f.HeaderText = column.ColumnName;
    f.DataField = column.ColumnName;

    if(column.DataType == dateType)
        f.DataFormatString = "{0:d}"; // Or whatever

    gvReport.Columns.Add(f);
}

gvReport.DataSource = dt;
gvReport.DataBind();
```

Comment: The above code works great (thanks Kevin Shea) but you need to add gvReport.Volumns.Clear(); before the "foreach" statement. If you don't, when the user clicks twice or more on a recreate of the GridView it will show an ever increasing repeat of the columns. In my case I let the user add any of a list of columns to show in the GridView and then hit a button to show the results. If the "Show Results button is clicked more than once I would get the columns repeated again and again every time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to format the values of an auto generated datetime column implementing the event ColumnAdded of the DataGridView:

```
    private void dataGridView_ColumnAdded(object sender, DataGridViewColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.ValueType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            e.Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your answer would work great for a DataGridView, but that's a control in WinForms. This question is about the ASP.NET GridView control which doesn't have a ColumnAdded event.

Answer (score -1):

Use `Eval` function to define string formation in aspx code:

```
<% # Eval("Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>
```

Complete Example:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <% # Eval("Date", "{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}") %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I'm auto generating the columns in gridview, All this is based on the selection we make in the form. What when users wont select any dates in their reports.