# How to remove the time part in Datefield of my data in gridview

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

How can we eliminate time part in `Datefield` in `Gridview`? Hence in my Database it has no timepart within, but when viewing in `Gridview` in ASP.net it appears Ex: I have my data inside the `DateField`:

```
2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM
```

I want to remove:

```
12:00:00 AM
```

So the field would display:

```
2016-05-01
```

aspx:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                AllowSorting="True" 
    HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" 
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
    ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
        PageSize="20" 
        onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
        EnableSortingAndPagingCallbacks="True">
        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" PreviousPageText="Previous" 
         NextPageText="Next" LastPageText="Last" Mode="NextPrevious" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
            </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: you can do it from mysql query when your retrieving data use DATE() FUNCTION

Comment: Or just format the appearance of the column in gridview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after searching through net, this were i came up, hence my gridview holds databound, i added the below code on my .aspx and hide the Original Column because this create new Column on my Gridview.

```
 <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField Datafield="Date" dataformatstring="{0:yyyy-MM-dd}" htmlencode ="false" HeaderText ="Date">
        </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
```

Hope can help you someday guys! thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

You can specify format in Eval expression on the label or column in the gridview. Below are two examples. One in a BoundField and the other in a TemplateField. Choose whichever suits. Add your other fields as needed.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridViewdoc" DataKeyNames="OrderId" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText ="Date" DataField="Dateordered" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label id="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Dateordered", "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**edit1:**

You should to alter the format of a column of a GridView from CodeBehind Add a RowDataBound to your grid view.

Then in the `GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)` method, you'll be able to access e which will provide you with access to the individual cells of that row where you can specify a formatter. (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25911627/how-to-change-datagridview-column-date-format-when-gridview-has-autogeneratecolu))

**edit2:**
In this edit I change datetime to date.
I have a student table in database and Gridview1 show it to the following:

[image: students]

Last column is datetime. For change format of this, I used this code:

```
<script runat="server">
void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[3].Text = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[3].Text));
    }
}
</script>
```

After do it, the result is shown below:

[image]

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: Please see the expanded answer.

Comment: Please update Gridview code to tell you where should add it.

Comment: im getting run time error:

"Callbacks are not supported on TemplateField because some controls cannot update properly in a callback.  Turn callbacks off on 'GridView1'.

Comment: Post your aspx and code behind so I can see what is going on.

Comment: @alisoltani, I've tried your suggestion but still the "12:00:00 AM" appears

Comment: is this included? <script runat="server">
though i did not include it still having same result..

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do it from a string you can use **substring_index**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', ' ', 1);
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', ' ', 1);
+---------------------------------------------------+
| SUBSTRING_INDEX('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', ' ', 1) |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-01                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

if you get the date from the database you can format it with **DATE_FORMAT**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

**sample**

```
MariaDB [yourschema]> SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT('2016-05-01 12:00:00 AM', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2016-05-01                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourschema]>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the date field in your gridview:

```
<asp:Label id="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("YourDate", "{0:yyyy/MM/dd}") %>' />
```

Comment: where should i put this? my gridview is data bound and connected to the mysql database