# How to change date format for the date column in datatable?

Tags: c#, string, date, datetime, datatable

I am filling the datable from database.
It contains two field: `DATE`, `TIME`

Both the fields are `datetime` column

I want to iterate through the datatable and change the date format for the `DATE` column i.e `dd/MM/yyyy`

```
int i = 0;
string d="";
foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
    d = dr["DATE"].ToString();
    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(d);
    d = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dataTable.Rows[i]["DATE"] = d;
    i++;
}
```

I get the following error

> *String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.*

Couldn't store `<15/02/2015>` in DATE Column.  Expected type is DateTime. How can I achieve it?

Comment: Can't be done. You could change the locale so dates default to having day first and month second with something like `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");`, but you would still get the associated time as well. Otherwise you would need to change the column type or change after the fact when your print or do whatever with dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Well*, you didn't tell us *how* you create your `dataTable` but here my thought..

If your both `DATE` and `TIME` columns are `DateTime`, then you need to supply them `Datetime` values. Not `string`.

In .NET Framework, [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) structure doesn't have *any* implicit format. It just have date and time values. You get it's string representation when you *try* to format it. That's why `15/02/2015` will be a `string` in your case, not a `DateTime`.

You get `FormatException` on your `Convert.ToDateTime` method probably because your `d` value was not a [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) for your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can use custom date and time parsing with using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

```
string s = "15/02/2015";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None,
                          out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Even if you do that, why do you wanna keep `string` values in a `datetime` typed column? That doesn't make sense *at all*. Even if you do that, since `.Rows` returns a [`DataRowCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you probably will get *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute* error since you try to modify your collection while you iterating it.

I suggest you to create another `DataTable` for your string values and add them to your `DateTime` values string representation as `dd/MM/yyyy` format like;

```
int i = 0;
string d = "";
var stringDataTable = new DataTable();
stringDataTable.Columns.Add("DATE", typeof(String));
stringDataTable.Columns.Add("TIME", typeof(String));

foreach(DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows)
{
   d = ((DateTime)dr["DATE"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   stringDataTable.Rows[i]["DATE"] = d;
   i++;
}
```