# Error no implicit conversion from string to system.Data.DataRow

Tags: c#

I am trying to format datetime field to show show only date in my C# code. I am currently getting a compile time error saying there is not implicit conversion from string to system.Data.DataRow. If I am providing an explicit cast like (DataRow) or (as DataRow) it still throwing compilation error. How do I achieve formatting of the column just to show date only

```cs
DataTable GetOrderSummaryDataTableByMember(string memberCode)
{
    DataTable memberOrderSummaryDataTableFiltered = MemberOrderDataDailySummaryData.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(row => row.Field<String>("Member") == memberCode)
        .OrderByDescending(row => row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate"))
        .Select(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") ) 
        .CopyToDataTable();

    return memberOrderSummaryDataTableFiltered;
}
```

Comment: What do you think happens here --> `.Select(row => Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate")).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") )`

Comment: Also, no-one should be using `Convert.ToDateTime` - yikes

Comment: I removed and changed it to this .Select(row => row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))   But still the same error

Comment: `row.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate")` returns a `DateTime?` already. Calling `Convert.ToDateTime` is superfluous. The `Select` returns an `IEnumerable<string>` but `CopyToDataTable` probably expects an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: hence I tried to explicitly cast it to DataRow

Comment: The error I get is cannot convert string to system.data.datarow

Comment: A string cannot be casted to DataRow. You would have to create a DataRow manually. But this cannot be done in a LINQ query. See: [How can I manually / programmatically create a DataRow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44010345/880990). What do you need this DataTable for? If you need it to populate a grid or listbox, then you can simply use a `List<string>` and call `.ToList()` instead of `.CopyToDataTable()`.

Comment: @Tom you're missing the point of the question - your `Select` returns the value of one column of each data row as a string. What are you trying to do with the select? It seems like you want to change the format of a date column by converting it to a string with a specific format.

Comment: Yes @DStanley, you got me right that is what I want to achieve. Didnt know it wouln't be straightforward

Comment: In that case you can either add a column to the datatable and set the value for each row with a loop (there may be a way to do it in one shot) or just return the datatable with a date column and set the format when you _display_ it. Personally I would just format it at display time (or report/serialization/whatever) rather than trying to manipulate the datatable.

Comment: Don't convert the date if you only intend to format it! See: [How to format DateTime columns in DataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4033113/880990).

Comment: There is a generic method that accepts datatable and exports to CSV .I am exporting the data to CSV

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to format datetime field to show show only date in my C# code.

`DateTime` does not *have* a textual format - a format only gets applied when you try to *display* the value (or serialize it if you don't want the default full serialization).

So you can either add a string column to your `DataTable` that shows the date as a string  (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28529757/1081897) for an example), or just apply the formatting when you display/serialize the date. Since there are many ways that `DataTable`s can be displayed, you'll have to search for solutions for the specific display structure you are using (DataGridView, report/JSON serialization, etc.)

The root cause of your error is that your `Select` is returning the value of one column as a string; it is not converting that column and returning the full row. I don't know that there's a non-hacky way to to that in a linq statement.

> There is a generic method that accepts datatable and exports to CSV

If the "generic method" uses the `DefaultCellStyle` property, it may be as simple as setting that property on the column:

```
dataGrid.Columns["OrderDate"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MM/dd/yyyy";
```

Comment: More correctly: DateTime has a format, but that format is and always will be binary, rather than anything text-based (still up-voted ;)

Comment: Fair enough Joel :)